# Pass multiple selected item id from list box to a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a table-valued parameter like this

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ss AS TABLE(ss1 integer);
```

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[T_TransactionSummary] 
    @locations dbo.ss readonly
as
begin
    ...............
    .............
    AND (Location_tbl.Locid IN (@locations))
```

I have a listbox that contains multiple items. I can select multiple items from my listbox. How can I pass multiple `Locationid` to my stored procedure if I always select one location from my listbox?

I pass them like this (when selecting one item only):

```
dim locid as integer = Lstbox.selectedItem
cmd.parameters.add("@locations", locid)
```

but I don't know how to pass multiple selected items together from listbox to stored procedure. If I selected multiple items from my listbox I want to pass all item id together to my stored procedure

I am working on vb.net windows forms..
sir in my case i am taking listbox selected item value like this:

```
 For i = 0 To cnt - 1
         Dim locationanme As String = LSTlocations.SelectedItems(i).ToString
       locid = RecordID("Locid", "Location_tbl", "LocName", locationanme)
   Next
        'End If
```

this locid i am passing to stored procedure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `For each` to get all selected items and then `Using` so that each time it loops the object is discarded after use, like:

```
For Each selectedItem As Object In ListBox1.SelectedItems
    Dim cmdText As String = "T_TransactionSummary"
    Dim locid As Integer = Int32.Parse(selectedItem.ToString())
    Using con As New SqlConnection("connection string here"), comm As New SqlCommand(cmdText), da As New SqlDataAdapter(comm)
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            comm.Parameters.Add("@location", SqlDbType.Int).Value = locid
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Dim dst As New DataSet
            da.Fill(dst)
    End Using
Next
```

Comment: sir..why you updating "SET Field1='test' "

Comment: That's only an example. You could change it as you like. But do you want exactly? You want to return records or return a single value or just do nothing but simply update your database (in which is the case here)?

Comment: sir..i not understand why you are updating database,,i edited my question

Comment: @user2951524: Updated my answer. Honestly I forgot that you are referring to stored procedure earlier ;-)

Comment: sir,,,after this how i can fill this value to one data set?

Comment: You could use DataReader and you can traverse it. However, you could also convert DataReader to DataTable. See update above.

Comment: sir now i am getting error Like this:Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'System.Data.IDataReader'.

Comment: @user2951524 : It should work. But anyway change SqlDataReader to IDataReader. See my update above.

Comment: Check my update again. I am using DataAdapter this time. I don't have something to test on this one because my database right now is not working.